# Language-C, while-loop, error for wrong input

Tags: c, loops

I really hope you can help me with this.
So this is just a part of my Code, which doesn't.
The part you see below doesn't work as intended.
So the output of the remaining salary is also correct, but if the input is out of the given range(whether it is a number or letter) it doesn't output an error, as id doesn't repeat the question.

```
int main()
{
  int variable1 = 0;
  double variable2 = 0;
  double variable3 = 0;
  double variable4 = 0;
  char variable5 = 0;

  printf("Type in a number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &variable1);

  while((variable1<0) || (variable1>5000000))
  {
    printf("Error\n");

    if((variable1>0) && (variable1<=5000000))
    {
      printf("Question that requires the answer y/Y or n/N?:\n");
      scanf(" %c", &variable5);
    }
   return 0;
  }

  variable2 = Function1(variable1, variable2);
  variable3 = Function2(variable1, variable2, variable3);
  variable4 = Function3(variable3, variable4, variable5);

  while((variable5!='j') || (variable5!='J') || ((variable5!='n') || (variable5!='N' )))
  {
    printf("Error\n");
    break;
    if((variable5=='j') || (variable5=='J') || ((variable5=='n') || (variable5=='N' )))
    return 0;
      if((variable1>0) && (variable1<=5000000))
    {  
      printf("Output1:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%12.2d\n", variable1);
      printf("Function1:\t\t\t%12.2lf\n", variable2);
      printf("Function2:\t%12.2lf\n" , variable3 + variable4);
      printf("Function3:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%12.2lf\n" , variable1+ variable2+ variable3 + variable4);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From the code you posted, please delete all that doesn't matter, until you end up with just a few lines that doesn't do what you expect. This is how things work at StackOverflow; we don't want to bother the people we ask with things that doesn't matter. Makes sense, right?

Comment: This is just a part (the main function) of my code. It doesn't output an error, when typing in a number or letter out of range.

Comment: Well, zoom in on the issue by deleting lines/code. Then show what you're left with here and explain. Use `printf()` statements or a debugger to see what your program does. You can't expect other people to analyse your code giving a vague description that it doesn't do what you expect. You need to work through this yourself; can be painful in the beginning I know, but it's part of the job. Don't get me wrong, I'm happy to help once you've boiled it all down to a well defined issue.

Comment: 'variable1' etc.....use meaningful names, else your code is very difficult to follow:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while((variable1<0) || (variable1>5000000))
{
  printf("Error\n");

  if((variable1>0) && (variable1<=5000000))
  {
    printf("Question that requeires the answer y/Y or n/N?:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &variable5);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Within the first while loop, remove `if((variable1>0) && (variable1<=5000000))`. That condition is the converse of what seems to be intended, and it is unnecessary to tests, since the loop just tested whether the value is invalid. This explains why the question prompt doesn't repeat.

Comment: Maybe mention that nothing in this loop ever changes `variable1` either, so even after the condition is fixed it is *still* not going to work (rather than not being entered it will be infinite). Also, the second while loop unmentioned in this answer, `while((variable5!='j') || (variable5!='J')...`, is flat wrong as well. All of those `||` conditions in that while-expression should be `&&`.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right, nothing in the loop changes variable1. Besides this, there is a `return 0` statement in the loop and the variable names are nondescriptive, so I'm not sure of the author's intent. In any case, there is a lot that could use fixing in this code.

Answer (score 0):

This code is equivalent to the following code.

```
int main()
{
  int variable1 = 0;
  double variable2 = 0;
  double variable3 = 0;
  double variable4 = 0;
  char variable5 = 0;

  printf("Type in a number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &variable1);

  while((variable1<0) || (variable1>5000000))
  {
    printf("Error\n");
    return 0;
  }

  variable2 = Function1(variable1, variable2);
  variable3 = Function2(variable1, variable2, variable3);
  variable4 = Function3(variable3, variable4, variable5);

  while((variable5!='j') || (variable5!='J') || ((variable5!='n') || (variable5!='N' )))
  {
    printf("Error\n");
    break;
  }
}
```

And the above code is equivalent to the following code.

```
int main()
{
  int variable1 = 0;

  printf("Type in a number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &variable1);

  if((variable1<0) || (variable1>5000000))
  {
    printf("Error\n");
    return 0;
  }

  printf("Error\n");
}
```